# Use an IDT (INTERRUPT DESCRIPTOR TABLE) assembly AT&T intel 32 bits

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on N450 board, I turns out that it already has IDT (Maybe built by BIOS !!).
When I call my ISR using INT $0x55 (using ItnCall), the code jumps to another random address instead of jumping to the ISR_0x55 !!!, why  ?

this is my code :

C code

```
    fill_interrupt(ISR_0x55,
                (unsigned int) isr0x55, //
                0x10,                 // Segment Selector
                0x8E);                // P=1, DPL=0, D=1

static void fill_interrupt(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    unsigned short *Interrupt_Address;

    /*address = idt_ptr.base + num * 8 byte*/
    Interrupt_Address = (unsigned short *)(idt_ptr.base + num*8);

    *(Interrupt_Address) = base&0xFFFF;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = sel;
    *(Interrupt_Address+2) = (flags<<8)&0xFF00;
    *(Interrupt_Address+3) = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

}
```

Assembly Code

```
IntCall:

    push %ebp   //save the context to swith back
    movl %esp,%ebp
//debug only
    nop
    nop
//debug only

    int $0x55
    pop %ebp //Return to the calling function
    ret
```

Comment: What segment descriptor have you setup for `0x10`? `0x08` is a more common value here IIRC.

Comment: Well, what's the "random address" it jumps to? Do you have a stack trace or register dump?

Comment: The address is 0x113c2 (address of my ISR_0x55 is 0x1151A), i did another ISR_0x33 and i have the same problem (code jumps to anohter address) it is in a middle of my code :-(,I checked the if there is some offset between the addresses but no way,  How do i make a stack trace ??

Comment: I Found it, it was a breakpoint, i don't know why but a breakpoint in INT crashes evrything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :), just a breakpoint, I put a breakpoint inside of the ISR, the debugger doesn't like it